# How to get an entity class name with thymeleaf & spring mvc in html page

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm starting spring mvc and thymeleaf with a little app where i have bank accounts. I have two types of bank accounts (Savings and Deposit), who are two Java classes inherited from a class Account.
When i pass an account object to my view, with thymeleaf, how can i retrieve the classname in order to know what account im dealing with ?

I guess i should use something like

```
<div>                      
    <label>Type :</label>
    <label th:text="${compte.class.name}"></label>
</div>
```

But i get the wrong name with package
`com.alain.comptemvc.entities.Compte$HibernateProxy$pzeNarBH`
I spend hours in thymeleaf documentation without finding any list of properties that i can look into, and intelli-j doesn't show me any auto-completion about it.
So more generaly, where can i look for these informations without trolling here !
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from my query to get the object.
i was using accountRepository.getOne(String id).
I changed it to 
`Optional<Compte> cp = compteRepository.findById(codeCpte);`
And now in the view :
`<label th:text="${compte.class.simpleName}"></label>`
give the good result.
But IntelliJ put me class.simpleName underline in red, with suggestion
"declare external variable in comment annotation"
Is it somethiing that i should really pay attention to ?